# mdadm auto grow raid

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a raid0/1 on lvm logical volumes.
I resized the logical volumes.
Now I want to resize the raid to use the complete logical volumes.
This can be done with

```
mdadm /dev/md? --grow -z newsize
```

When I do only

```
mdadm /dev/md? --grow
```

I get `mdadm: no changes to --grow`

But somehow I can't figure out how to calculate the `newsize` argument. Is there a way to tell mdadm to grow to the biggest possible size? If not, how do I calculate the biggest possible size of the raid to use for the `newsize` argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `mdadm /dev/md0 --grow --size=max`

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm

> -z, --size=
>   Amount (in Kibibytes) of space to use from each drive in RAID1/4/5/6.
>   This must be a multiple of the chunk
>   size, and must leave about 128Kb of
>   space at the end of the drive for the
>   RAID superblock. If this is not
>   specified (as it normally is not) the
>   smallest drive (or partition) sets the
>   size, though if there is a variance
>   among the drives of greater than 1%, a
>   warning is issued.
>
> This value can be set with --grow for RAID level 1/4/5/6. If the array
>   was created with a size smaller than
>   the currently active drives, the extra
>   space can be accessed using --grow.
>   **The size can be given as max which
>   means to choose the largest size that
>   fits on all current drives.**